# Is it possible to create a photo sharing app like Instagram using Smartface

Tags: instagram, smartface.io

Is it possible to create a photo sharing app like Instagram using Smartface?

I've tried cloning Instagram using another software however it wasn't successful.

Thankyou 
I really appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create photo sharing app.If you do backend anyway that you can do, you can do front end of application by using Smartface

Answer (score 0):

To get and display an image is simple. If you want to implement the "filters" part, then the story is different. SmartFace doesn't have a image processing option/library built in. So you need to implement this feature yourself.

A good option for beginners might be another product like: B4A https://www.b4x.com/b4a.html .. where the community have already created a lot of libraries/resources.